# How Do I Disable Twitter Bootstrap Icons in Roots Theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, font-awesome

I'm using the [Roots WordPress theme](http://www.rootstheme.com/), although I'm sure the process will be the same for any Bootstrap enabled site.

I'd like to disable the built-in Twitter Bootstrap icons and use Font Awesome's in their place.  I have loaded Font Awesome's, and they're working, but some icons like `icon-envelope` seem to load icons from both sets.

Is there a way to disable the default Twitter Bootstrap icons?

Answer (score 2):

You need to recompile the LESS source in the Roots repo to CSS, making the changes found on the Font Awesome website's [section on Integration](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration).

### Lazy Way

I did a diff of the `bootstrap.css` in the Roots repo and the `bootstrap.min.css` in the Bootstrap repo, and turns out they're identical.  So, technically, you should just be able to use the [Bootstrap Customize page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html), uncheck the `Icons` checkbox, and then hit the enormous DOWNLOAD button at the bottom.

Replace the `bootstrap.css` in your Roots theme with the `bootstrap.min.css` in the `css` directory of the downloaded zip (renaming it, of course).

Now just use the CSS files that Font Awesome provides.

Done.

### Long (Thorough) Way

1. Clone a copy of the [Roots repo](https://github.com/retlehs/roots).
2. Install some form of LESS compiler (see [Twitter Bootstrap page on LESS compiling](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling))
3. Copy Font Awesome files into repo, including `font-awesome.less` into `roots/css/less` directory.
4. Edit the `bootstrap.less`, replacing `@import "sprites.less";` with `@import "font-awesome.less";`
5. Update the paths to the fonts, in the `font-awesome.less` file.
6. Compile `bootstrap.less` to `bootstrap.css`. (*Don't forget minification*)
7. Use that file and upload the fonts to the directories you specified.

#### The choice is yours. Either should work.

---

### Update

[BootstrapCDN](http://bootstrapcdn.com) now serves an icon-less version of Bootstrap, as well as the FontAwesome CSS files.  That makes the "**Lazy Way**" all the more simple.